# Regex поиск строки в HTML таблице

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения

Нужно найти строку в таблице у которой в первой колонке слово "NVIDIA RTX 3080". Раньше работало такое выражение: `//*[@id="myTable"]/tbody/tr[20]`

Но оказалось что номер нужной строки может поменяться, хотя раньше такого не было. Помогите составить правильный regex

Пример таблицы:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Модель</th>
<th data-sort-method="number">Цена</th>
<th data-sort-method="number">Прибыль</th>
<th data-sort-method="number">Окупаемость</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td data-head="Модель">NVIDIA RTX 3090</td>
<td data-head="Цена">145769.07 ₽</td>
<td data-head="Прибыль">&nbsp;377.89 ₽ 11714.59 ₽</td>
<td data-head="Окупаемость" data-conditional="385">385 дней</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td data-head="Модель">NVIDIA RTX 3080</td>
<td data-head="Цена">72993.19 ₽</td>
<td data-head="Прибыль">&nbsp;302.31 ₽ 9371.61 ₽</td>
<td data-head="Окупаемость" data-conditional="241">241 дней</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td data-head="Модель">NVIDIA GTX 1050 Ti</td>
<td data-head="Цена">5709.71 ₽</td>
<td data-head="Прибыль">&nbsp;26.94 ₽ 835.14 ₽</td>
<td data-head="Окупаемость" data-conditional="211">211 дней</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Регулярное выражение должно вернуть строку:

```
<tr>
<td data-head="Модель">NVIDIA RTX 3080</td>
<td data-head="Цена">72993.19 ₽</td>
<td data-head="Прибыль">&nbsp;302.31 ₽ 9371.61 ₽</td>
<td data-head="Окупаемость" data-conditional="241">241 дней</td>
</tr>
```

Значения во всех колонках, кроме первой, регулярно меняются.

Comment: ищите по `data-head="Модель"` и проверяйте, содержит ли строка (`str.includes()`) необходимое значение

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>\n<td data-head="Модель">NVIDIA RTX 3090<\/td>\n.*\n.*\n.*\n<\/tr>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]